# Dynamically resize background image according to different screen size

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I displays a splash Screen when my app loads,There is a background image in the splash screen,I problem is how can I make fit this image in all types of blackberry models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that many BlackBerry devices have different screen resolutions and even different aspect ratios.  So if you just use a single image and resize (stretch and/or squish) it to fit the current screen, you're going to distort the image (or pattern).  As I see it, there are two main approaches:

1) Use a different image for each screen resolution.  There are about 7 different resolutions that cover most of the in-market devices (240x260, 240x320, 320x240, 360x400, 360x480, 480x320, 480x360)

2) If it's a regular background pattern as opposed to a picture or logo, just have one image in the app that's big enough to cover the largest screen size (480x360) and for all other screen sizes just clip it.  In fact, I think this should happen automatically if you just set the background image - anything that can't be displayed on the screen will be clipped.

While approach #2 is better in terms of reducing application size, I'm going to guess that since you're asking this question the background you're thinking of using isn't a regular pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method would be to use the setBorder method of whatever screen/field needs a stretched background. For example:

```
Border b = BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder (new XYEdges (), bitmap);
field.setBorder(b);
```

In my experience this results in the background image being stretched and provides the simplest method for fitting the size you need. I have only ever used it for fields though and never a MainScreen so it might not work for you.